# JSON Not grabbed by $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

***Final solution:*** There was something wrong with the formatting of my `.json` file deeper down than the snippet I included in the question. Everything is working now. Big thanks to everyone in the comments and I'm marking @TWLATL's answer as correct because it's a nicely formatted function solution I can use in projects later.

I'm trying to access my `data.json` file from `script.js` (both in the `root` directory) and it doesn't seem to be running at all. Before I put in error handling, I was getting no indication the function ran. Thanks to comments, I replaced `.error` with `.fail`, but I still can't figure out why it's failing.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>JSON Render</h1>
    <div id="fileViewer"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    console.log('json grabbed')
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    console.log("GetJSON Error!");
    console.log(data);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( "SUCCESS: " );
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function( data ) {
        console.log( "AJAX ERROR: " );
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

**data.json (sample)**

```
{
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Main Folder",
        "type": "folder"
      },
      {
        "name": "Private folder",
        "type": "folder"
      }
    ]
}
```

I've been looking around on Stack Overflow and no solutions I've found seem to solve my problem. Help!

Edit: Added jQuery CDN to my `index.html`. It was there. I just forgot to put it in the question.

Edit 2: Updated script.js to reflect the code that is returning the screenshots below. (screenshot cut off in the middle of the object. I can include more if the context of the object is actually relevant.)
[image: console output]

**Edit 3: New AJAX Error handling:**
The new ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( "SUCCESS: " );
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("textStatus: ",textStatus);
        console.log("errorThrown: ",errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And I am now wonderfully getting this console output:
[image: new console output]

Comment: are you running it on server?

Comment: what is jquery version?

Comment: No server. The entire project is client side and I need it to stay that way.

Comment: Are you running this within a local web server or just opening an html file in the browser? If its the latter you can't access files on the file system like that. Its against CORS.

Comment: make sure you are accessing index.html over http (like `http://localhost/index.html`) protocol in web browser!!

Comment: I'm accessing the page through http://127.0.0.1:8887/

Comment: I mean... the error message clearly states that .error isn't a function. that's because... it isn't a function. what you're looking for is `.fail`. Add a proper error handler and look for the error messages presented in the 2nd and third parameters.

Comment: @KevinB I've never seen `.fail` before and every solution on stack overflow was using `.error`. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: You must not be looking at jquery solutions then. .error has been gone for a long time. This is also covered well in the documentation.

Comment: well then you should check console in debugger/web inspector.

Comment: @KevinB I'll admit a lot of the solution I've been finding are 4+ years old, which is why I created my own question. `.fail` did return that there was an error so I'm about to edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: so.... what was the error?

Comment: @KevinB sorting it out now in Dev Tools. Will report back.

Comment: Maybe you picked the wrong `jquery` version, as the `slim` version excludes all the `jquery animation effects`.

Comment: excluding animation effects wouldn't make ajax go to the error handler.

Comment: just use $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
      alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
    },
    error: function( data ) {
      alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
    }
  });  and see if you get error again.

Comment: @techLove: I'm getting an error still, but the response Data being sent back still seems to have all the data I need, which is bizarre...

Comment: @KevinB: I'm getting the same error with your solution as with techLove's

Comment: @JDB it is not. I've solved that part of my problem back before I even created this question

Comment: @Rokitar what is the error using ajax func???

Comment: add two more parameters to your error handler and log them. separately. error handling is covered in the docs. http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @techLove That's the weirdest part, there is no error message anywhere. Nothing failed in my network anywhere. It returns an object that I can manipulate really nicely. Which is what I want, but that shouldn't be coming from an error response.

Comment: The object even returns a 200 status...

Comment: that indicates the problem is likely a parseerror or something related. Which you would know for sure if you logged all three parameters in the fail callback.

Comment: may be u can add some screenshots from console. it will help

Comment: What are the other parameters I should be logging? And Screenshots being added in 1 min.

Comment: The second and third arguments to the `error:` function contain the reason for the error. Try logging them instead of `data`.

Comment: the error indicates your json is invalid. The sample you provided is valid, so... guessing that sample isn't actually what you have. Are you building json by hand? don't. most major languages have methods that will convert data structures to json for you.

Comment: Final edit on post. Solved. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a slightly modified version of your code, I have it returning the JSON just fine:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DMLyJa1Quj7ofszn5Y7o?p=info

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  var items;

  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      console.log('json grabbed');
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      items = data.children;
      console.log(items);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log("Error!");
    });

}); // close document.ready
```

Jquery uses .done now for the success method. In that block just assign your data.children item to a variable and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone in the comments I was able to sort out the issue. It was actually a JSON formatting issue. I used this site to find where the problem was: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/